# 400 BadRequest response with .NET Core but not .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, httprequest, .net-4.5, .net-core-2.1

I had the link http://www.swensens.com.vn/#huong-vi-tinh-yeu which I need to validate that it's still working or not by request and getting the StatusCode.

It's simple like that

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync(@"http://www.swensens.com.vn/#huong-vi-tinh-yeu");           
Console.Write(result.StatusCode);
```

When I tested with .NET Core 2.1, it gets 400 Bad Request. I suspect the "#huong-vi-tinh-yeu" may cause the problem because I received 200 OK without them. But when I tested it again in .NET Framework, the full link is perfectly getting 200 OK with no problem occurred.

I also tested by using 3rd library such as Flurl, RestSharp in .NET Core but the results are only one with 400 Bad Request.

Another testing on the website https://httpstatus.io still 200 OK
[image: 1]

I want to keep .NET Core because my current Azure Function system is written through .NET Core.

So what is the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a known bug. I reported that bug some time ago on the Github repository: [[2.1] Redirect with location having an anchor fails in a HTTP 400 on some servers #34728](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34728)

It seems this bug was introduced in .NET Core 2.1, and fixed in .NET Core 3.

As a temporary workaround, you can call this before you make any HTTP requests, which will disable the faulting code:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

Comment: It's seem nothing changed when I inserted the workaround, I may continue test it in .NET Core 3 and update soon

Comment: @TấnNguyên That might work in your case. I used this test code, which worked for me: `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false); HttpClient hc = new HttpClient(); var result = await hc.GetStringAsync("http://corefx-net.cloudapp.net/Redirect.ashx?statuscode=302&uri=%2FEcho.ashx%23something"); Console.WriteLine(result);`.

Comment: Oops my mistake, I inserted after httpclient declaration so it still got HTTP 400. Your test code is worked with HTTP 200!!!! Thank you so much